What's the name of that famous economics paper that was written using only short words?
Some time ago I came across a famous economics paper that was written using only very simple very short words.
I cannot remember the exact criteria for choosing the words. All I remember is that almost all of the words were very common and very short (e.g. shorter than 5 letters).
I think it was written by an economist in response to critics who said that his writing is too hard to understand or something like that, I can't remember exactly.
Does anyone know which paper I'm talking about?

There's no need for that EDIT at the end. Accepting the answer is how you indicate that it's the answer you were looking for.

Samuelson, Paul A. "Why we should not make mean log of wealth big though years to act are long." Journal of Banking & Finance 3.4 (1979): 305-307.

P. Cook, A ‘One Line’ Proof of the Slutsky Equation, American Economic Review, 62 (1972), 139
He said the common classroom proof was tedious and unintuitive.

Your link is not working for me, but thank you for having included a full reference.
